# Janus GridEX Designer does not get Opened

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, janus, gridex

I've been working with Janus GridEx in Windows Forms for a long time. I'm afraid I'm suddenly unable to open the GridEx designer on Visual Studio 2019, which makes real work fairly impossible or at least unproductive; The Problem showed up Out of nowhere and I can not find the cause...

It happens in all of my projects, So I Thought the Problem should be in The IDE which I'm Using;
I tried repairing Visual Studio from Installer But That Didn't Work

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall another machine enviroment.

It´s temporary solution